# Display elements from an arraylist into a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have a problem when I try to display elements from an Arraylist into my servlet. When I try to print the size of the list, it works, but I can`t get the elements from that list I receive null in the console.

MyServlet

```
public BoardServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param currentCategoryID 
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    int currentCategoryID =  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("currentCategoryID").toString());
    List listBoards = DBoard.getBoardByCategory(currentCategoryID);

    request.setAttribute("boards",listBoards);


    ArrayList<Board> list =new ArrayList<Board>();
    //storing passed value from jsp
    list = (ArrayList<Board>)request.getAttribute("boards");
    System.out.println(list.size());

    for(Board board : list) {

        System.out.println(board.getNameBoard());
    }

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Board.jsp").forward(
            request, response);             

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



}
```

MyDaoClass

```
public static  List<Board> getBoardByCategory(int idCategory) {
    Connection con = null;
    int count=0;
    List<Board> boardList = new ArrayList<Board>();
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Cristian\\workspace\\Forum Application1\\database.db");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Board WHERE idCategory=?";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setInt(1, idCategory);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            count++;
            int id_Board = rs.getInt("idBoard");
            int id_Category = rs.getInt("idCategory");
            String board_name = rs.getString("nameBoard");
            Board obj = new Board(id_Board,id_Category,board_name);
            boardList.add(obj);         

        }
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(count==0) {boardList=null;}
    return boardList;
}
 private static Connection connect() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Projects\\RSA80Workspace\\Forum Application\\database.db");
                System.out.println("connected!");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the query is not having null board_name for the provided idCategory.

Comment: I check it, for eq, when i want to see how many elements I have for a specific idCategory, it works. The problem is that when I try to print these elements.

Comment: Yeah i got it. I want you to confirm that running same query in database should not give null board name. You code is printing null for elements because it seems board.getNameBoard() is null for the given idCategory.

Comment: In the database I receive the board name for each idCategory.

Comment: Cross check that column name is nameBoard and can you try printing board.getCategoryId()

Comment: I got it. Thank you mate!

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: It was from my constructor. I appreciate your time trying to solve the problem.